# How to have different input and output sizes for a Drake system

Tags: drake

I am trying to write a system that takes as input the state of a free body and gives as output the desired state of a revolute joint.

Hence the input port should take a vector of size 13 and the output port should give a vector of size 2.

For now, I just want to extract one value from the input state, so I tried something like this:

```
ball_state = Variable("ball_state")
desired_theta_system = builder.AddSystem(SymbolicVectorSystem(input=[ball_state], state=[], dynamics=[], output=[ball_state[6], 0]))
```

However, this did not work, as the `ball_state` variable is not subscriptable.

How can I do this? Do I need to derive LeafSystem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could certainly write a small LeafSystem, but you could accomplish this one with a [MatrixGain](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1systems_1_1_matrix_gain.html) system (e.g. with D =

```
[0, ..., 0, 1, 0, ...] ;
[0, ... 0].
```